# Can I have one HTTP API for native apps and a (React) single page application?

Tags: api, cookies, single-page-application, jwt

I want to build a RESTful HTTP API and the first client will be a React app. For API authentication I want to use JSON web tokens, as I find the approach intuitive and they seem to be a well supported popular choice.

My main concern here is the storage of the JWT token in the React app. Supposedly, it is not safe to store a token in local storage because the token could be exposed in a XSS attack. Instead, the recommended way is to store the token in a HttpOnly safe cookie. Of course this results in the possibility of CSRF attacks which have to be dealt with accordingly. The OWASP CSRF cheat sheet mentions 'Double Submit Cookies' and 'Encrypted Token Pattern' as stateless countermeasures.

Now I wonder how these techniques mix with native clients accessing the API. Do I have to implement the whole cookie based logic in native clients as well? To me this has a bad smells as I complicate the API in order to support one specific (albeit important) client technology.

Is there an agreed upon way to do JWT authentication based HTTP API's that support both browser based as well as native access?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending cookies with react native websockets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37246446/sending-cookies-with-react-native-websockets)