# Sending cookies with react native websockets

Tags: cookies, reactjs, websocket, react-native

So I'm using react native [websockets](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html#websocket) but cannot figure out how i can include cookies in websockets, any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

At the moment there is no automatic way to do it. There is a third (undocumented) parameter for the WebSocket constructor to pass custom HTTP headers to the connect request.

```
WebSocket(url, '', {Cookie: 'key=value'});
```

This works on iOS, I haven't tested it on Android but the WebSocket implementation looks like it is supported there as well.

If you just need to pass a session id or auth token, it's probably easier to pass it as a GET param in the url. Relying on undocumented behavior in a rapidly changing framework can be dangerous.

Comment: Even though it is specified that both string and array should work (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) only `[]` worked on Chrome and Firefox as empty protocol parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the WebSocket declaration, you can see that the header keys should be strings.

**This works for me:**

```js
var headers = {};
headers["cookie"] = `cookieName=${cookieValue}`;

const ws = new WebSocket(`wss://www.somesite.com/socket`, null, {
    headers
});
```

**not this:**

```js
{
  headers: {
    cookie: `cookieName=${cookieValue}`
  }
}
```

Comment: but  i can't test network inspact , response header success or not ? 
does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

As of React Native 0.38, this should [happen automatically](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/9114) on Android.

There's currently [an open PR](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/10575) for making it work automatically on iOS as well, but at the moment it seems there's still some work left there around testing.

In the meanwhile, you could follow the "manual approach" proposed [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/7167#issue-150507851):

> Manual approach is to retrieve the cookie through a cookie manager plugin and pass it as headers to web socket.

(Once you have the cookie from the manager, the way to pass it to the websocket is, as mentioned [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37251989/3412775), to use the undocumented 3rd parameter of `WebSocket`.)