# How to use React Native's WebSocket with cookies

Tags: cookies, react-native, websocket

I have a real-time server with WebSocket and cookies. to authentication i should send two cookies to server with Websocket.

how can i use React Native's Websocket with cookies

according to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42962786/6375548) "As of React Native 0.38, this should happen automatically on Android" but HOW??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is undocumented feature:

React-Native's websocket structure is below:

ws = new WebSocket(url, protocole, extraHeader);

your send extraHeader as object (such as Cookie, authentication-key and etc) to websocket server.

it's tested in android and working fine. and according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37251989/6375548) it's working in iOS as well as Android